# DB2 SQL Function with dynamic return value

Tags: sql, function, db2, db2-luw

I have the following working DB2 SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selector (param VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS TABLE (id INT, CMD VARCHAR(1024), ATTR CHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL 
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
RETURN
  SELECT id, cmd, attr
      FROM test.commandtbl c
      WHERE c.attr=param;
```

Calling it like:

```
select * from table (selector('c'))!
```

The problem is that I want the return table to be dynamic in size and type. 
I want to use the function with a lot of return fields and and while testing I don't want to always check the return table it everything still matches.

For example:

Test1 is with 5 return columns: INT, INT, INT, CHAR(10), VARCHAR(100)

Test2 is with 20 return columns: 10 VARCHAR(100) and 10 INT

and so on.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What DB2 version/platform?

Comment: Windows 7,  DB2 v10

Comment: There's no DB2 v10 on Windows -- there's 10.1 and 10.5, so which one?

Comment: Version v10.5, Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can consider SQL a statically typed language in that it has little ability to discover its variable (e.g. column) and object (e.g. result set) data types at run time; you have to declare types at the statement compilation time. In other words, what you want to achieve is not possible.

There is a concept of a [generic table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0057283.html) which allows you to define a Java-based UDF that returns *some* result set:

```
CREATE FUNCTION selector (param VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS GENERIC TABLE
EXTERNAL NAME...
```

However, you still need to declare the result set structure on the receiving end:

```
SELECT t.* FROM TABLE (selector('c')) AS t (foo INT, bar INT, baz VARCHAR(10)...)
```

Comment: When I use that I get SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selector (param VARCHAR(3))
    RETURNS GENERIC TABLE
    EXTERNAL NAME 'selector'

    DETERMINISTIC

    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 

    RETURN
      SELECT id, cmd, attr
          FROM test.commandtbl c
          WHERE c.attr=param;`

  `SELECT t.* FROM TABLE (selector('c')) AS t (id INT, cmd VARCHAR(1024), attr VARCHAR(10))!`

Comment: Yea I just missed out the LANGUAGE JAVA and PARAMETER STYLE DB2GENERAL, but that gives the same error

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selector (param VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS GENERIC TABLE
EXTERNAL NAME 'selector'
LANGUAGE JAVA
PARAMETER STYLE DB2GENERAL
RETURN
      SELECT c.id, c.cmd, c.attr
          FROM table (test.commandtbl) AS c
          WHERE c.attr=param!`
         
         
  `SELECT t.* FROM TABLE (selector('c')) AS t (id INT, cmd VARCHAR(1024), attr VARCHAR(10))!`

Comment: Sorry, I'll repeat it one more time and then I'm done: **it has to be a Java function**, written in the, you know, Java language, not SQL PL.

Comment: Ah ok... Well I need it to run in SQL PL not JAVA. So thanks for the help but this does not work for me