# Calling a stored procedure from a function

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, db2, return-value

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEARCH_SELECT (IN searchKey varchar(30), OUT id INT, OUT cmd VARCHAR(1024), OUT attr CHAR(10))

LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA 
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE result_set_1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
        SELECT id, cmd, attr FROM test.commandtbl c WHERE c.attr = searchKey;   
    OPEN result_set_1;
END!
```

And I want to call that from the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_selector (param VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS TABLE (id INT, CMD VARCHAR(1024), ATTR CHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL 
READS SQL DATA 

EXTERNAL ACTION 
BEGIN

  call SEARCH_SELECT(param);

 END!
```

The reason why is that I need to call the result as a table like I do with a function i.e.

```
select * from table(select_selector('a'))
```

and not like a procedure

```
call SEARCH_SELECT('a')
```

How can I get that to work?

The question here is how to call a stored procedure with a parameter from within a function and get the same result as the stored procedure would have returned so I can call the procedure like a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 SQL Function with dynamic return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135261/db2-sql-function-with-dynamic-return-value)

Comment: Added explain why it is not